Do Left Shift and Right Shift have better performance compared to multiply and divide operations?
If I want to do the fastest way to calculate x * 2, which one should I use?
x << 1

or
x * 2

With the same logical thinking, if I want to do the fastest way to calculate x / 2, which one should I use?
x >> 1

or
x / 2

Why?

Yes, they are faster, but they come at the cost of readability and ease of understanding. The performance difference is generally so small, and meaningless for JS, that using the standard mathematical operators is the default approach.

@RoryMcCrossan Could you elaborate on why they are faster? You can then convert it into an answer right away.

There's not as much in it as I thought, roughly a 2% difference in advantage of the bitwise operators https://jsperf.app/tegeto. Even more reason not to bother with them in JS (unless you are actually working with bit values)

of course, limited to 32bit integers

multiplication/division and left/right shifting are not the same operation. They are close in many parameters but still aren't one and the same. Consider 3 / 2 === 1.5 and 3 >> 1 === 1. So, shifting is more similar to integer division. Again, not exactly the same as a division (even if we disregard dividing odd numbers): 40000000000 /2  === 20000000000 and 40000000000 >> 1  === 672647168 because of bitwise operators only work with 32-bit numbers.

At any rate, the real resource you need to start with is: Which is faster?

my browsers do 1 (chromium based) to 2 (mozilla) BILLION operations (* and <<) per second - with a difference of under 0.1% (well within the margin of error for such measurements) ... so .. do what you want - unless you're doing billions of such calculations, it really does not matter one iota

at the processor level [->register] a shift operation only takes a few cycles, while a multiplication goes through complex arithmetic optimization which are necessarily more expensive in terms of cycles and loops, even in the case of a simple multiplication/division by 2 [or a multiple of 2]. This kind of optimization is only useful in cases of absolute performance necessity, as in the case of a rocket order; there is also the case of the first Ariane 5 launch, destroyed due to a 32-bit register overflow.

They're very different operations: bit shifting (and in fact, all bitwise operations) force the result into being a 32 bit integer. Multiply and divide do not. In effect: bit operations can only be (correctly) used with integers, in order to perform 32 bit math. Regular arithmetic operations can be used with all Numbers, which are 64 bit floating point numbers with safe integers up to 53 bits. So performance wise, if you need multiplication by two, bit shifting 0b11111111111111111111111111111111 << 1 will be 0% efficient, 100% of the time, because it's not multiplying by 2.

There's no difference:
` Chrome/127
---------------------------------------------------
shift     ■ 1.00x | x1000000000 246 246 252 255 262
multiply  ■ 1.00x | x1000000000 246 252 254 257 258
--------------------------------------------------- `

Open in the playground


// @benchmark shift
2 << 1

// @benchmark multiply
2 * 2

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




Yes, the results are similar, but I suspect the action of the code optimizer here, which is a good thing.
